# PHP onclick doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I've been trying to figure out how I can get this onclick to work in my php script. It worked fine until I tried to add the postid variable to the url. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
echo "<div id='reply_button' onclick=\"location.href='addreply.php?id='".$postid."\"></div>"
```

Comment: Look at your HTML output

Comment: Not sure probably you may want to remove the quote before `id=` and add one in the end.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a strangely misplaced single quote. You need this:

```
echo "<div id='reply_button' onclick=\"location.href='addreply.php?id=".$postid."'\"></div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location.href='addreply.php?id='".$postid."
```

why are you using a single quote before id, simply remove it

```
echo "<div id='reply_button' onclick=\"location.href='addreply.php?id=".$postid."'\"></div>"
```

Comment: Long day not sure how I didn't noticed that, however after removing the single quote it still doesn't seem to work.